# Classrooms and students puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

> My school has many classes. Any two students share exactly one class. Any two classes share exactly one student. A class must have at minimum $3$ students, and there is at least one class with $17$ students. How many students attend my school?

How do I approach this question? How do I determine whether or not this question has an exact numerical answer?

This is difficult... help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeking a [projective plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane) with lines containing $17$ points (i.e., projective planes of order $16$).  These have $16^2+16+1=273$ points (i.e., students) and $273$ lines (i.e., classes).  There are a list $16$ inequivalent such projective planes listed [here](http://www.uwyo.edu/moorhouse/pub/planes16/).

---

We need to check that every class has size $17$ and every student attends $17$ classes.

Let $C$ be the class of size $17$ and $x$ be a student not in $C$ (which exists, since there are "many" classes).  From the assumptions, every class $x$ attends has a unique student in $C$ and any student $y \in C$ shares a unique class with $x$.  Hence $x$ attends exactly $17$ classes.

Let $N$ be the set of classes attended by $x$ (we know $|N|=17$ from the above), and let $z$ be a class outside of $N$.  From the assumptions, any student in $z$ shares a unique class in $N$ and any class in $N$ shares a unique student with $z$.  Hence $z$ contains exactly $|N|=17$ students.

We now need to go back and repeat the argument for arbitrary $x$ and arbitrary $C$ for which $x \not\in C$ where we know $|C|=17$.

We conclude that every class has $17$ students and every student attends $17$ classes.  Thus we indeed have a projective plane of order $16$.

The number of points (and lines) in a projective plane of order $n$ is $n^2+n+1$.

Comment: As a high school student, I have no idea why I was asked this question, because I clearly don't understand the answer. Can you recommend a quick introduction to everything I need to know about projective planes so that I can understand the solution? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: We really only need two additional things to what I wrote below the line: (a) the definition of a projective plane and (b) knowledge that a projective plane of order $n$ has $n^2+n+1$ points.  These should be understandable to a high school student.  (But, I agree, it does seem quite a tricky question at that level.  Maybe there's another approach that I'm unaware of.)

Comment: Okay, orders of projective planes are a bit iffy to me because they appear out of nowhere like magic, but the rest of the reasoning is very clever. Thanks!